# C# Cannot call constructor for class B which has an attribute of class A. ERR: Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, constructor, attributes

So I'm really going crazy with this:

```
public class foo
{
    int attributeA;

    public foo(int a)
    {
        attributeA = a;
    }
}

public class goo
{
    foo attributeA;
    
    public goo(int a)
    {
        ERROR HERE-> attributeA = foo(a);
    }
}
```

I get an error when trying to call the constructor for the foo class foo in order to make an object of the class goo.
The error I get is: Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method

I really don't get it, why is it non invocable? How can I fix it? I just want to create a simple class which uses another class as one of its attributes and It's already taken me like 5 hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use `new`, which is needed for calling constructors.

`attributeA = foo(a);`

should be

`attributeA = new foo(a);`